# Definition of Planck area and Planck volume

Tags: quantum-mechanics, units, physical-constants

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units, the Planck area is defined as the square of the Planck length, and the Planck volume as the cube of the Planck length.

\begin{equation} l_\text{P}^2 = \frac{\hbar G}{c^3} \end{equation}
\begin{equation} l_\text{P}^3 = \left( \frac{\hbar G}{c^3} \right)^{\frac{3}{2}} = \sqrt{\frac{(\hbar G)^3}{c^9}} \end{equation}

To me this seems quite arbitrary. Why is the Planck area not for example an equilateral triangle with sidelength $l_P$, or a circle with diameter $l_P$? In both cases the area would be smaller than that of the respective square. Maybe the circle is not optimal because a surface cannot be covered fully with only circles. But with triangles this is possible, so I don't see a reason why it should be a square or why it's even reasonable to assume a square.

Comment: The unit of area has to be some constant multiple of the square of the unit of length.  The simplest constant is 1.

Comment: read the first line of the wiki page you linked. Shape doesn't really enter into the question

Answer (score 3):

### For the same reason that the Metric area is 1m$^2$ and the Metric volume is 1m$^3$

Or the Imperial area is 1ft$^2$ and the Imperial volume is 1ft$^3$.

Area is one length multiplied by another and therefore has units of square [whatever the unit of length is]. Volume is length x length x length and has units of cubed [whatever the unit of length is].